# Python: Storing multiple dictionaries after replacing categoricals with integers

Tags: python, string, dictionary, integer, categorical-data

My data looks like this:

```
source  browser sex age country class
SEO Chrome  M   39  Japan   0
Ads Chrome  F   53  United States   0
SEO Opera   M   53  United States   1
SEO Safari  M   41  NULL    0
Ads Safari  M   45  United States   0
Ads Chrome  M   18  Canada  0
```

In trying to get it ready for machine learning, I wrote a function to replace categoricals with integers:

```
def str2int(data):
    y2= data
    S = set(y2) #set 
    D = dict(zip(S, range(len(S)))) # assign each string an integer, and put it in a dict
    Y = [D[y2_] for y2_ in y2] # store class labels as ints
    return Y
```

I then call it using the below to convert all string columns to integers:

```
cols=['sex','browser','country','source']
for col in cols:
    df_fraud[col] = convert_str_int(df_fraud[col])
```

I would like to store the dictionary associated with each column and call it later, which I could simply say "return Y, D" in the def function, but I am not sure how I would include it in my for function below.

Frankly, I am not sure what the best way to store these references in dictionaries are and am open to suggestions.

I have simplified the example below:

This is not working when using the suggested code. Any ideas?

```
def str2int(data):
    y2= data
    S = set(y2) #set 
    D = dict( zip(S, range(len(S))) ) # assign each string an integer, and put it in a dict
    Y = [D[y2_] for y2_ in y2] # store class labels as ints
    return Y, D

def make_str2int(data):
    categories = set(data) 
    return dict(zip(categories, range(len(categories))))

raw_data = {
        'names': ['A','B','B','D','D','E','B','B','E','F'],
        'gender': ['M','F','F','F','F','M','M','M','M','M']} 

str2int={}
cols = ['names', 'gender']
for col in cols:
    str2int[col] = make_str2int(df_fraud[col])
```

Comment: I think you don't need the intermediate `y2` variable.

Comment: Also, you may be interested in the `values` method of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested, and I'm not sure to understand exactly how you intend to use the dictionaries, but here are my suggestions.

You could store the dictionaries in a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
def make_str2int(data):
    categories = set(data) 
    return dict(zip(categories, range(len(categories))

str2int = {}
cols = ['sex', 'browser', 'country', 'source']
for col in cols:
    str2int[col] = make_str2int(df_fraud[col])
```

(Assuming `df_fraud` represents your table (you didn't make this clear in your question.))

And then, if you want the categories existing in one column `col`, you can call:

```
str2int[col].keys()
```

If you want the corresponding numbers:

```
str2int[col].values()
```

If you want the number associated to a categorical value `cat_val` in a known column `col`:

```
str2int[col][cat_val]
```

#### Edit: Applying on your `raw_data` example

```
def make_str2int(data):
    categories = set(data) 
    return dict(zip(categories, range(len(categories))))

raw_data = {
    'names': ['A','B','B','D','D','E','B','B','E','F'],
    'gender': ['M','F','F','F','F','M','M','M','M','M']} 

str2int={}
cols = raw_data.keys()
for col in cols:
    str2int[col] = make_str2int(raw_data[col])

print "Conversion examples:"

element = raw_data['names'][3]
print "%s -> %s" % (element, str2int['names'][element])

element = raw_data['gender'][2]
print "%s -> %s" % (element, str2int['gender'][element])
```

Output:

```
Conversion examples:
D -> 3
F -> 1
```

Comment: I tried your code, bli, thank you. It is not working. I have created a simplified example for your reference. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I tested the simplified example you gave, and it fails with a `NameError` because the data is in `raw_data`, but then it tries to access an undefined variable `df_fraud`. If I substitute `df_fraud` with `raw_data`, the code runs without complaining.

Comment: Thanks, sorry. That's what happens when coding at 2 AM